# Split word phrases and give out all subgroups in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a table item name which is like this :

```
Microsoft Word
Adobe Premiere
Paint
Mozila Firefox
Adobe Photoshop CS7
Windows Movie Maker
```

I want to select the data (table product, column name) become like this :

```
Microsoft
Word
Microsoft Word
Adobe
PremiereF
Adobe Premier
Paint
Mozila firefox
Adobe 
Photoshop
CS7
Adobe Photoshop
Photoshop CS7
Windows
Movie
Maker
```

I'm using Postgres.... is it possible to make like that?

Answer (score 1):

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=50e1cbe2673c5ffe398186ef292a8052)

It is not really clear to me what's your expected result.

For `Adobe Photoshop CS7` your results are:

```
Adobe 
Photoshop
CS7
Adobe Photoshop
Photoshop CS7
```

What about the origin string `Adobe Photoshop CS7`? For the solution I am expecting you are wanting all subphrase in the right order. So the solution should include the`Adobe Photoshop CS7`result. This is indicated by your other results which include the origin strings.

---

(1) First step: get all subphrases from beginning:

```
String: A B C D E

A
A B
A B C
A B C D
A B C D E
```

Query

```
WITH single_words AS (
    SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS nth_word FROM (         -- B
        SELECT id, regexp_split_to_table(phrase, '\s') as word FROM phrases  -- A
    )s
)
SELECT 
    array_agg(word) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY nth_word) as phrase_part  -- C
FROM single_words;
```

A: The `WITH` query makes the query simpler for writing the same subquery only one time (used in (2)). The `regexp_split_to_table` function splits the string at whitespaces and puts each word into a single line.

B: The window function `row_number` adds a counter to the words which indicates the origin position within the original string (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html).

C: The window function `array_agg() OVER (... ORDER BY nth_word)` aggregates the words into a list. The `ORDER BY` is used to get an ascending word list indicated by the original word position (without the `ORDER BY` the `array_agg` would add all words of the phrase getting the original string for all `word` rows)

---

(2) Second step: get all subphrases from all starting points:

```
String: A B C D E

A
B
C
D
E
A B
B C
C D
D E
A B C
B C D
C D E
A B C D
B C D E
A B C D E
```

Query

```
WITH single_words AS (                                                    -- A
    SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS nth_word FROM (
        SELECT id, regexp_split_to_table(phrase, '\s') as word FROM phrases
    )s
)
SELECT 
   *, 
   array_agg(b.word) OVER (PARTITION BY a.id, a.nth_word ORDER BY a.id, a.nth_word, b.nth_word) as phrase_part -- C
FROM single_words a                                                       -- B
JOIN single_words b                                       
ON (a.id = b.id AND a.nth_word <= b.nth_word)
```

A: Same as in (1)

B: cross join the phrases with themself; better speaking: join on word with each following of the same phrase

C: this window function aggregates the phrase words to the given result.

---

If you don't like the array you could convert the result into a string with the function `array_to_string(phrase_part, ' ')`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `regexp_split_to_array`:

```
CREATE TABLE s(c TEXT);
INSERT INTO s(c) VALUES('Microsoft Word'), ('Adobe Premiere');

SELECT unnest(regexp_split_to_array(s.c, '\s+'))
FROM s
UNION ALL
SELECT c
FROM s;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/OYJS97452)**

**EDIT:**

To get every combination you could use:

```
WITH src AS (
    SELECT id,name, rn::int, (MAX(rn) OVER(PARTITION BY id))::int AS m_rn
    FROM s, 
     unnest(regexp_split_to_array(s.c, '\s+')) WITH ORDINALITY AS sub(name,rn)
)
SELECT id, string_agg(b.Name ,' ' ORDER BY rn) AS combination
FROM (SELECT p.id, p.Name, p.rn, RIGHT(o.n::bit(16)::text, m_rn) AS bitmap
      FROM src AS p
      CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, 100000) AS o(n)     
      WHERE o.n < 2 ^ m_rn) b
WHERE SUBSTRING(b.bitmap, b.rn, 1) = '1'
GROUP BY b.id, b.bitmap
ORDER BY id, b.bitmap;
```

**[Rextester Demo 2](http://rextester.com/TRCA6212)**

Comment: It just get a word, how two words, three words ?

Comment: @adn Just add `UNION ALL`

Comment: @LukaszSzozda your solution will not work. The expected solution includes not only the single words and the origin strings but only all sub parts. E.g. a string with 3 words should result in one or two 2 words results next to the 3 one words and 1 three word results.

Comment: Nice one. It's a complete different idea to my one. Now it's up to @adn ... I am not sure if 'Adobe CS7' is valid. Meaning maybe only direct following words should be possible to form a subphrase. But this is only my interpretation of the problem :)

Comment: @S-Man Thanks for spotting it, it is quite old question :)